# Confused at updating content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I use CakePHP 1.3.10, jQuery for the JsHelper and jQueryUI. On my page there's a link called "Login" and when a user clicks on it, a dialog opens with the loginform inside. Everything works fine but the CakePHP part by submitting the form is totally screwed.

I have two login templates "login.ctp" and "ajax_login.ctp". So when the dialog opens the first time, "Login.ctp" is shown and by submitting wrong login data, "ajax_login.ctp" comes as "update". Everything works fine, but when I submit the form in "ajax_login.ctp" - it redirects me to http://localhost/project/login - which obviously shouldnt.

After searching for the bug, I found out, that the html is all correct. The error is that the id-attribut from the submit button of the "ajax_login.ctp" is another one than in the javascript codeblock. Yes, I know I could use a fix id, but I guess this is not correct solution because I think CakePHP is working correct, only me is doing a mistake(?).

Here is an example:
*users/login.ctp*

```
<div id="login-dialog" title="Login">
  <?php
    echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Js->submit(
        'Login', 
        array(
            'type' => 'html', 
            'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
            'update' => '#login-dialog'
        )
    );
    echo $this->Form->end();
  ?>
</div>
```

*users/ajax_login.ctp*

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('User', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'));
echo $this->Form->input('email');
echo $this->Form->input('password');
echo $this->Js->submit(
    'Login', 
    array(
        'type' => 'html', 
        'url' => array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
        'update' => '#login-dialog'
    )
);
echo $this->Form->end();
?>
```

*users_controller.php* - The **login()** function

```
public function login() {
        if($this->RequestHandler->isAjax() == true) {
            $this->layout = 'ajax';
            if($this->Auth->login() === 1) {
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'account'));
            }
            $this->render('ajax_login');
        }
        return $this->Auth->login();
    }
```

Submitbutton Id at the first time I open the login-dialog: **#submit-1033269670**
Submitbutton Id after the first login failed (wrong data): **#submit-2037877124**

As you can see, at the second time, the Id is another one, but the javascript havent changed it. The javascript event refers to the first id **#submit-1033269670**

I hope my explaination isnt too confusing ^^. Looking forward to your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, from your description, here's a rough explanation of what I think is happening. Cake's Js Helper *generates* the jQuery and writes it into views that render in layouts. The Js Helper appends a dynamically generated number to the end of each generated element's id to ensure all generated element ids are unique (and keeps track of them for callbacks such as your `'update'=>'#whatever-id'`.)

One problem here is, these are simply two different views - not an ajax layout, a view, and an slick little snippet of form code in an ajax-ready view element. You've got 2 otherwise identical forms and from the sounds of it, Cake is rendering both (correctly, for what it's been told to do) as follows:

1. users/login - first call renders flat users/login.ctp view
2. attempting to login by clicking the jquery-enabled button causes RequestHandler to detect an ajax response when the login() method fires as the form action,
3. which in turn contains logic that manually renders the second users/ajax_login.ctp view
4. and since they're 2 different forms in 2 different views, Cake generates a unique ids for each.

The different callback id's are a dead giveaway.

**What you need** is an 1.) ajax layout in your views/layouts, 2.) a users/login.ctp view file that originally pulls 3.) the form as an element rather than an entire view unto itself, and 4.) probably an element to render after login() succeeds and calls account().

A nominal gesture of setting up the Auth component, ie allowing / disallowing controller actions and defining a default login redirect:

```
// this could live in app_controller, to be 
// application-wide, or users_controller
function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index','view', 'account');
        // and you probably want something like this:
        $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('controller' => 'users',
                                           'action' => 'account');
}
```

The Auth component remembers what controller/action the user requested before being prompted to login and will redirect the user to that controller action if it exists; otherwise, it will redirect the user to whatever is specified in the loginRedirect property.

In your users/login method:

```
//change this:
if($this->Auth->login() === 1) {
// to this:
if($this->Auth->user() != null) {
// and you probably want something like this:
 $this->redirect(array('action' => 'account'));
```

`$this->Auth->login()` is used to **manually** log a user in, for example as the callback of a `signup()` method, etc.

Here's your ajax layout:

```
// views/layouts/ajax.ctp
<?=$content_for_layout;?>
```

Your views/users/login.ctp:

```
<div id="login-dialog" title="Login">
    <?= $this->element('login') ?>
</div>
```

Your views/elements/login.ctp:

```
<?php
echo $this->Session->flash('auth');
echo $this->Form->create(...) /* etc. the rest of your form */
?>
```

Your views/elements/account.ctp:

```
<div class="user-account">
<? // Markup, results of an `account()` action, etc. ?>
</div>
```

Your controllers/users_controller.php method:

```
var $components = array('Auth', 'Session', 'RequestHandler', 
                        'Js'=>array('Jquery'));

public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'ajax';
    if ($this->Auth->user() != null) {
        $this->render('elements/account', 'ajax'); // enforces ajax layout
    } else {
        // whatever you want to do here, ie. log attempts, flash message, etc.
        $this->Session->flash('Please login'); 
    }
}
```

http://book.cakephp.org/view/57/Controller-Methods (esp flow control)

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1250/Authentication

The real goodies are in the api:
http://api.cakephp.org/class/auth-component

HTH. :) Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but this doesn't work either. I adopted the part with the views, so I created your _elements/login.ctp_ and your _users/login.ctp_. But now when I submit the form, it returns the _users/login.ctp_ inside itself plus its hidden because the id **login-dialog** has the css attribute _display: none;_.

So then I thought "Okay, then lets return the _elements/login.ctp_ view." but as you already said, the Javascript generates unique submit id's and this way also didnt work.

Comment: Okay, that's progress: when you submit the form, it's returning the AJAX'd users/login action. If your form processing directs it to the login action, that means either the login is finding $this->Auth->users() is null. What's being sent? Stick `debug($this->Auth)` at the top of the login() method to get an idea of what happens when you login. Don't forget the sessions component and again, have you gotten this to work without ajax?